# Convert CSV to well-structured JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-itertools

I have a CSV file that is structured as below :

`Store, Region, District, MallName, Location`

```
1234,90,910,MallA,GMT
4567,87,902,MallB,EST
2468,90,811,MallC,PST
1357,87,902,MallD,CST
```

What I was able to accomplish with my iterative brow-beating was getting a format like so:

```
{
  "90": {
    "910": {
      "1234": {
        "name": "MallA",
        "location": "GMT"
      }
    },
    "811": {
      "2468": {
        "name": "MallB",
        "location": "PST"
      }
    }
  },
  "87": {
    "902": {
      "4567": {
        "name": "MallB",
        "location": "EST"
      },
      "1357": {
        "name": "MallD",
        "location": "CST"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code below is stripped down to match the sample data set I provided but you get the idea as to what is happening. Again, it's very iterative and non-pythonic which I'm trying to also move towards. (If anyone feels the defined procedures would be worthwhile to post I can).

```
#************
#   Main()
#************
dictHierarchy = {}

with open(getFilePath(), 'r') as f:
    content = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines()]

for data in content:
    data = data.split(",")

    myRegion = data[1]
    myDistrict = data[2]
    myName = data[3]
    myLocation = data[4]
    myStore = data[0]

    if myRegion in dictHierarchy:
        #check for District
        if myDistrict in dictHierarchy[myRegion]:
            #checkforStore
            dictHierarchy[myRegion][myDistrict].update({myStore:addStoreDetails(data)})
        else:
            #add district
            dictHierarchy[myRegion].update({myDistrict:addStore(data)}) 
    else:
        #add region
        dictHierarchy.update({myRegion:addDistrict(data)})

with open('hierarchy.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(dictHierarchy, outfile)
```

Obsessive compulsive me looked at the JSON output above and thought that to someone blindly opening the file it looks like a hodge-podge. What I was hoping to do for plain-text readability is group the data and throw it into JSON format as so:

```
{"Regions":[
    {"Region":"90", "Districts":[
        {"District":"910", "Stores":[
            {"Store":"1234", "name":"MallA", "location":"GMT"}]},
        {"District":"811", "Stores":[
            {"Store":"2468", "name":"MallC", "location":"PST"}]}]},
    {"Region":"87", "Districts":[
        {"District":"902", "Stores":[
            {"Store":"4567", "name":"MallB", "location":"EST"},
            {"Store":"1357", "name":"MallD", "location":"CST"}]}]}]}
```

Long story short I wasted quite some time today trying to sort out how to actually populate the data structure in Python and essentially ended up no where. Is there a clean, pythonic way to achieve this? Is it even worth the effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added headers to your input like:

```
Store,Region,District,name,location
1234,90,910,MallA,GMT
4567,87,902,MallB,EST
2468,90,811,MallC,PST
1357,87,902,MallD,CST
```

then used python [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [group by](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) like this:

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby, ifilter
from operator import itemgetter

data = []

with open('in.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    regions = []

    regions_dict = sorted(list(reader), key=itemgetter('Region'))
    for region_id, region_group in groupby(regions_dict, itemgetter('Region')):

        districts = []
        regions.append({'Region': region_id, 'Districts': districts})

        districts_dict = sorted(region_group, key=itemgetter('District'))
        for district_id, district_group in groupby(districts_dict, itemgetter('District')):
            districts.append({'District': district_id, 'Stores': list(district_group)})

print regions
```

Comment: Implementing this solution is putting me in that Zoolander "It's so simple. The files are in the computer." moment. Being newer to Python this was like magic. Thank you for taking the time on this solution.

Comment: usually too busy during the day, sorry, try leaving a note here, will love to help if I can

Comment: Completely understand. I'll hit you up in the morning. I made some modifications (which worked) but just wanted an opinion on efficiency/methodology. Great solution again - had to do some heavy reading on what you used to grasp the module calls.